# Create New Spreadsheet of data from many Excel workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, merge

In retrospect, this is an issue of data-collection, but I want to see if there is an easy way to do it without doing each file.

I have about 350 separate Excel workbooks. Each workbook has a bit of information pertaining to one individual.

What I want to do is create a simply spreadsheet of everyone with the necessary data, so it is then usable.

To give you an idea. A1 lists "Name" with B1 having the person's name. 
A2 has "Last 4 SSN" and B2 has the 4 digits.

Then A3 has the word "Year", then A4 "2014 est", A5 - "2013", A6 - "2012, etc, to 2009.

Then in Row 3 from B to N there are different pieces of information.

What I want to do, if possible, is have a master spreadsheet with columns of name, last 4 ssn, and then years for each of the pieces of data. ie. 2013-Interest

Is this even possible?I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: I would think it is possible, as manually doing this would take a long time, but you could do it. Have you tried anything to date so far?

Comment: Are you looking for a one-time consolidation, or do you want to continue updating the individual sheets and have those updates pushed to (or pulled by) the master?

Comment: Take a look about consolidating data from multiple worksheets; this could give you a good understanding. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/consolidate-data-from-multiple-worksheets-in-a-single-worksheet-HP010342300.aspx?CTT=1

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. You can start a Query from an Excel table. If you spreadsheets are in separate files it has a great function to import all the files in a Windows Folder in a single step and append all their data together (assuming the file columns are consistent). If they are multiple sheets in a single file then you will need multiple Queries, which you can combine together using the Append command.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/append-queries-HA104149760.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

There is also an Unpivot command to transform data stored in multiple columns into multiple rows - maybe that would solve your multi-Year challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the data from all the workbooks in a folder by using VBA. If you are familiar with VBA, you can add the following code to a workbook and run it. It will create a new workbook with all the data combined from the files in the folder you designate in the `FolderPath`.

**Note: As a safeguard, it would be a good idea to make a copy of all files into a separate folder while you run this code.**

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range

    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet. 
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\Peter\invoices\"

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Open a workbook in the folder
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

        ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
        ' Modify this range for your workbooks. 
        ' It can span multiple rows.
        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A9:C9")

        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and 
        ' be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all 
    ' data is readable.
    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Read the notes carefully to modify the areas specific to your needs. Here is the source of this code if you need to refer to it - [Merging Data from Multiple Workbooks into a Summary Workbook in Excel 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg549168%28v=office.14%29.aspx).